# How to specify the jsdoc rule for ESLint to recognize unused parameters?

Tags: eslint, jsdoc

In my projects I have an ESLint rule for unused parameters that can be silenced by adding a leading underscore to the parameter name:

```js
    /**
     * Set the outer alternative number for this context node. Default
     *  implementation does nothing to avoid backing field overhead for
     *  trees that don't need it.  Create
     *  a subclass of ParserRuleContext with backing field and set
     *  option contextSuperClass.
     *
     * @param altNumber The alt number to set.
     */
    public setAltNumber = (_altNumber: number): void => {
    };
```

This method can be overridden which is why I want the documentation to use the parameter name without the leading underscore. However, that conflicts with the ESLint [jsdoc/require-param](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-jsdoc#eslint-plugin-jsdoc-rules-require-param) rule.

I neither want to disable the unused parameter rule nor the the require-param rule. How can I satisfy both? Is there a setting that allows require-param to detect the parameter even with a leading underscore?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `no-unused-vars` [eslint rule](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-vars).

package.json

```
"rules": {
    "jsdoc/require-param": ["error"],
    "no-unused-vars": ["error", {"args": "after-used"}],
},
```